# How to provision docker images?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, docker

**First a bit of background:**

I currently use VMWare ESXi for my virtual machines. Some servers needs to be up 24/7 and others I tear down and re-create from templates when I need to.

After playing around with docker I see I can accomplish much of the above and also much faster (at least for my Linux machines).

But what I like about VMware ESXi is a good graphical overview of the global resources for the host, all running/stopped servers, their hardware resources and the ability with a few clicks to add more RAM, CPU or disk space to individual servers.

Regarding tweaking memory/CPU seems you can do the same in docker:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler

just a bit more low-level.

So at the moment I don't really see a path where I could completely move from a VMWare/ESXi managed infrastructure to a pure docker infrastructure and based on:

https://www.upguard.com/articles/docker-vs.-vmware-how-do-they-stack-up

it sounds like this is not really the point with docker either - to replace existing hypervisors like VMWare/Hyper-V etc.

**Then the question:**

*Or are the companies that run a pure docker setup for their whole machine farm and if so how do they manage resources and keep an overview of all servers?*

Comment: Look at 'vSphere Integrated Containers'

Comment: From https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install it seems docker requires Hyper-V at the moment

Comment: No, docker for Windows needs Windows - 99% of docker images are for linux - also you didn't mention Windows in any way whatsoever until now

Comment: Hyper-v is part of windows and you cannot run both hyper-v an VMware at the same from what I understand, that was what I meant with that comment

Answer (score 0):

A "pure" docker setup adds another layer of abstraction. Docker hosts will be VMs running on a hypervisor or in a cloud. To run docker containers you need a Linux host which needs to run somewhere. The resources of the docker hosts will than need somekind of docker cluster manager like `kubernetes` or `swarm`.

So in short: there is no path to completely replace a hypervisor setup with a pure docker solution.

Comment: Ok makes sense, you have answered my question, on a side note, from: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows it seems docker requires Hyper-V when on Windows, so since I am based on VMWare at the moment I assume I have to change to hyper-V before I can get started with docker for windows (ignoring the Docker Toolbox approach)?

Comment: I have heard of that. As far as I know Windows 10 will start some kind of VM in the background. I'm certain that you will be better off doing it yourself. Meaning: Setting up a Linux VM on your VMware and run docker on it. This Hyper-V way of doing things is IMHO just confusing. As most people use Docker with Linux you will find better resources on how to set it up. I don't see a good reason to switch to Hyper-V for you. However this Hyper-V way is perfectly fine for local development.